# how to used onblur in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

HI now i using to onblur in jquery but it's not working i m searching google but not find solution

can u please check this  and tell me where i m wrong .

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
    function myFunction() {
    var rohit = $('#fname').val();
        alert("Your name is" + rohit);
 };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Enter your name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" onblur="myFunction()">
```

Error show is

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined
```

Comment: Define `myFunction` outside document-ready handler in the global scope. Even better if you bind it using jQuery like `$("#fname").on('blur', myFunction);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently your myfunction() is defined in dom ready handler, which will not be accessible to the dom element. Put that outside ready handler, it will  work. But I will prefer to use jquery event handler to bind blur event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fname").blur(function() {
        var rohit = $('#fname').val();
        alert("Your name is" + rohit);
    });
});
```

Note: put your jquery reference at the head tag. Because it should be loaded before you using its functions.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following snippet:

```
$(function(){
  $("#fname").blur(function(e){
    // do stuff on blur;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Enter your name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" onblur="myFunction()">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function myFunction() {
        var rohit = $('#fname').val();
        alert("Your name is" + rohit);
    };

</script>
```

You can also defined as. Running jsfiddle is https://jsfiddle.net/p5urjog7/

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fname").on('blur', function() {
        var rohit = $('#fname').val();
        alert("Your name is" + rohit);
    });
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define function before the input element, like at starting of body to call like in this fiddle.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t0nz0yt6/)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        var rohit = $('#fname').val();
        alert("Your name is" + rohit);
    };
<script>
Enter your name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" onblur="myFunction()">
```

At start i also got error of function is undefined, but when i wrap in head, it started working.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a run below snippet and check the demo:

Thanks

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fname").blur(function() {
        var fnameVal = $('#fname').val();
        $('#showoutput').text(fnameVal);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Enter your name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" />
<p>Output on blur: <span id="showoutput"></span></p>
```